# In Eclipse, can I override "spaces for tabs" for specific file types?

Tags: eclipse, tabs

In the vast majority of cases I want Eclipse to insert spaces for tabs, and I have the "insert spaces for tabs" box checked in the "Text Editors" preferences.

However, I occasionally edit files that require real tab characters (e.g. Robot Framework). For the moment the only way I can insert tabs in these files is to open them in a different text editor.

Is there any way to override the "spaces for tabs" behavior for a specific type of file, or even allow a tab to be inserted "just this once" with some special keystroke or command? Even when I copy/paste a tab from another file Eclipse converts it to spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AnyEdit plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) can automatically convert tabs to spaces on Save.  It also supports exclusion filters, so you could add your special file names/types to avoid the conversion.